# How do I convert flash video to html5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe, html5-video

I want to convert a flash video to HTML5 on the fly. Not having to download it and upload it and then convert it again to HTML5 video?

This is a video link source code from Adobe

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-

flash"src="/swf/software/flash/about/flash_about_793x170.swf" width="793" height="225" 

id="shell_object" name="shell_object" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="high" scale="noscale" 

salign="tl" wmode="opaque" title="Adobe Flash Player">
```

Flash Source Link

> > **/swf/software/flash/about/flash_about_793x170.swf**

Actual HTML Link

> > http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

How would I convert it on the fly and show it in a device that is only capable of playing HTML5 video? In other words an on the fly Flash (*.swf) to HTML5 converter Is there like a API that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a converter like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org). The command would look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i flashvid.swf html5.mp4
```

And the html:

```
<video>
    <source src="html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: I think the OP meant converting it in the browser on the fly